# How to read only numbers from file until EOF in C

Tags: c, function, file, numbers

I have this function to find the max and min value of numbers in file with uknown text("ADS 50 d 15"). It works fine with only digits in the file, but when there is a characters it just stops.

```
{
    int n;
    int min = INT_MAX, max = INT_MIN;
    int flag = 0;
    rewind(f);

    while (fscanf(f, "%d", &n) != EOF)
    {

        if (ferror(f))
        {
            perror("Error:");
        }
        if (flag == 0)
        {
            min = n;
            max = n;
            flag = 1;
        }
        if (min>n)
            min = n;
        if (max<n)
            max = n;
    }
    printf("\nMax value: %d\nMin value: %d\n", max, min);
}
```

Comment: If the input doesn't match an integer, fscanf returns 0, not `EOF`. Notice also that `ferror(f)` can only be true whenever `fscanf` already returned `EOF`, therefore your `if` is never run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fscanf will return EOF after reaching the end of the file. It will return 1 on successful scanning an integer. If the input is not an integer, it will return 0 and the problem input has to be removed.

```
{
    int n;
    int min = INT_MAX, max = INT_MIN;
    int result = 0;
    char skip = 0;

    rewind ( f);
    while ( ( result = fscanf ( f, "%d", &n)) != EOF)
    {

        if (result == 0)
        {
            fscanf ( f, "%c", &skip);//remove a character and try again
        }
        else
        {
            if (min>n)
                min = n;
            if (max<n)
                max = n;
        }
    }
    printf("\nMax value: %d\nMin value: %d\n", max, min);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following approach as it is shown in this demonstrative program. You have to use the `fscanf` instead of `scanf` used in this program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    int min, max;
    size_t n = 0;

    while ( 1 )
    {
        char c;
        int x = 0;

        int success = scanf( "%d%c", &x, &c );

        if ( success == EOF ) break;

        if (success != 2 || !isspace( ( unsigned char )c ) )
        {
            scanf("%*[^ \t\n]");
            clearerr(stdin);
        }
        else if ( n++ == 0 )
        {
            min = max = x;
        }
        else if ( max < x )
        {
            max = x;
        }
        else if ( x < min )
        {
            min = x;
        }
    }

    if ( n )
    {
        printf( "\nThere were enetered %zu values\nmax value: %d\nMin value: %d\n", 
            n, max, min );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If the input looks like

```
1 2 3 4 5a a6 7 b 8
```

then the output will be

```
There were enetered 6 values
max value: 8
Min value: 1
```